# Jenkins: How to execute a powershell script in the PostBuild section?

Tags: powershell, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I've some code that I need to execute on the Postbuild section(Because I need a file to be present(changelog) which can be only generated in the PostBuild event). And because I need this task to be executed only when a successfull built has been done.

Now I'm unable to select a Powershell script in the PostBuild section(I've installed the powershell addon, and I'm able to add a powershell in the build section).

How can I achieve that? In this task I need to move severals files(builds, obfuscations stuff, and changelog).

Thank you

Comment: well, if there's the cmd task, just launch powershell and execute your script?

Comment: @4c74356b41 Is there a `cmd` task?  Is this an additional plugin because I don't have it. For now, while searching guys trying to use `PowerShell` script through `batch` files were all unsuccessfull, this is why I didn't searched in this direction.

Comment: there's nothing wrong with powershell via cmd

Comment: @4c74356b41 Since I don't have either the batch option for the postbuild, doesn't change the problem.

Comment: ok, lets step back a little bit, why can't you just add a powershell step as the last one?

Comment: @4c74356b41 It was my initial tought, but the addon that generate the changelog(which I've to move with other files) is only allowed in the postbuild section, and I've to move it after

Comment: @4c74356b41  I saw that: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Post+build+task but then I will not have access to the environment variables of jenkins?

Comment: Not sure, you can resort to calling another job after this one finishes and do whatever you need, but you would have to pass the environment variables, thou

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **groovy post-build step**. Then **launch your powershell script from groovy**.